# import duplicates in android contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

i am importing .vcf file in android but it imports duplicates records.

Code : 
method fo import contact :

```
 public void doImport(final String fileName, final boolean replace) {
    try {

            File vcfFile = new File(fileName);

            final BufferedReader vcfBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));



            final long maxlen = vcfFile.length();

    // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            long importStatus = 0;

            synchronized (syncMonitor) {
                    mAction = Action.IMPORT;
                    syncFileName = fileName;
                    }

            SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            SQLiteStatement querySyncId = db.compileStatement("SELECT " + SYNCID + " FROM " + SYNCDATA_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + PERSONID + "=?");
            SQLiteStatement queryPersonId = db.compileStatement("SELECT " + PERSONID + " FROM " + SYNCDATA_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + SYNCID + "=?");
            SQLiteStatement insertSyncId = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO  " + SYNCDATA_TABLE_NAME + " (" + PERSONID + "," + SYNCID + ") VALUES (?,?)");
            Contact parseContact = new Contact(querySyncId, queryPersonId, insertSyncId);
                    try {
                            long ret = 0;
                            do  {
                                    ret = parseContact.parseVCard(vcfBuffer);
                                    if (ret >= 0) {
                                            parseContact.addContact(getApplicationContext(), 0, replace);
                                            importStatus += parseContact.getParseLen();

                                            // Update the progress bar
                      //   app.updateProgress((int) (100 * importStatus / maxlen));
                                    }
                            } while (ret > 0);

                            db.close();
                        //    app.updateProgress(100);
                    synchronized (syncMonitor) {
                            mAction = Action.IDLE;
                          //  showNotification();
                    }
                 //   stopSelf();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
         }
     }).start();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         //   app.updateStatus("File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Import", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + SYNCDATA_TABLE_NAME + " ("
                    + PERSONID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + SYNCID + " TEXT UNIQUE"
                    +");");
        }

                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                        // No need to do anything --- this is version 1

                }
    }
```

Contact.java :
[Click here Contact.java](https://code.google.com/p/vcardio/source/browse/src/vcard/io/Contact.java)

Code Link : [Click here to get whole code of contact import and export](https://code.google.com/p/vcardio/source/browse/src/vcard/io/VCardIO.java)

how to Restrict to import duplicates in above code

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the field "X-IRMC-LUID" in the VCard is not the same as the one saved in the addressbook. If its the same then the VCard entry is a duplicate.

There isn't a specification on how to generate such field and AFAIK is done in different ways, mostly duplicating the UID field or the position in the VCard. This open source app contains some code examples that may be useful: http://code.google.com/p/vcardio/